# livedata coroutine does not observe the data

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I use MVVM architecture in my project. When it first called, it works. but after that, it does not work.
here is my code.

```
 fun loadYgosuData() : LiveData<ArrayList<YgosuData>> {
   Log.d(TAG, "loadYgosuData()...")
   return liveData {
       Log.d(TAG, "liveData Scope running....")
       val element = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           Jsoup.connect("https://www.ygosu.com/community/real_article")
               .get()
               .select("div.board_wrap tbody tr")
       }
       emit(setYgosuData(element))
   }
```

}

```
fun setYgosuData(tmpDoc: Elements?) : ArrayList<YgosuData> {
    var tmpList = ArrayList<YgosuData>()
    if (tmpDoc != null) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "element : $tmpDoc")
        for (e in tmpDoc) {
            var title = e.select("td.tit a")
            var name = e.select("td.name a")
            var read = e.select("td.read")
            var date = e.select("td.date")
            var url = e.select("td.tit a").attr("href").toString()
            var tmpYgosuData = YgosuData(
                title = title.text(),
                name = name.text(),
                read = read.text(),
                date = date.text(),
                url = url
            )
            tmpList.add(tmpYgosuData)

        }


    }
    Log.d(TAG, "여기2 ${tmpList.toString()}")
    return tmpList
}
```

Could you help me please?
Thank you.

Comment: can you please show your code where you call `loadYgosuData` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)

> The liveData building block serves as a structured concurrency primitive between coroutines and LiveData. The code block starts executing when LiveData becomes active and is automatically canceled after a configurable timeout when the LiveData becomes inactive. If it is canceled before completion, it is restarted if the LiveData becomes active again. If it completed successfully in a previous run, it doesn't restart. Note that it is restarted only if canceled automatically. If the block is canceled for any other reason (e.g. throwing a CancelationException), it is not restarted.

That's why it works for the first time as you mentioned.

Solution1: combine liveData with [Transformations](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations)

```
private val body: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

val YgousData = body.switchMap {
    liveData {
        Log.d(TAG, "liveData Scope running....")
        val element = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Jsoup.connect("https://www.ygosu.com/community/real_article")
                .get()
                .select("div.board_wrap tbody tr")
        }
        emit(setYgosuData(element))
    }
}

fun callApi(param:String){
    body.value = param
}
```

You can change the `body` based on which  you  want to trigger api call

Solution2: You can do api call explicitly and then post the data to livedata (w/o using livedata builder)

Comment: This is what I was really looking for. Thanks a lot!